# How to send multipart file to spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-batch

I am working on setting up a sprint boot rest API, to accept a multipart file and implement batch processing. I checked many articles about the implementation of spring batch, all of it uses a file stored somewhere in a folder. I would want an API to accept a multipart file and then send it to the spring batch item reader so that the process of updating the records to the DB would happen. The file that will be sent from the frontend would be a CSV file.

Any help would be amazing.
Thanks.

Comment: If rest api controller receive MultipartFile parameter, you can convert to string format (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143743/read-data-from-multipartfile-which-has-csv-uploaded-from-browser) and you can change the option that maximum size of using only memory to save file data by maxInMemorySize value of CommonMultipartFile.